# Android EditTextPreference disable Dialog

Tags: java, android, edittextpreference

I want to disable(not show) the Dialog, when i click the EditTextPreference in a Preference Activity.

When i click the EditTextPreference, a pop up dialog show. Now i want to disable this. I try set an onclicklistener, but the dialog show same.

```
public class Settings extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);       
   EditTextPreference userName=(EditTextPreference) findPreference("prefUsername");
    userName.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

            return false;
        }
    }); ...
```

I try add this to the EditTextPreference:  android:clickable="false", but nothing.

Comment: you should add some of your code, to show what all exactly have you tried?

Comment: Hi!I updated, my question, with some code.

Comment: If you need the EditText dialog sometimes, you could use userName.getDialog.dismiss() if you don't want it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disable it.

Use

```
android:enabled="false"
```

in XML. Or to disable in runtime,

```
userName.setEnabled(false);
```

Actually, if you do not want a dialog, you probably should use simple `Preference` instead of `EditTextPreference`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I use just Preference, and works. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

try to replace

```
EditTextPreference
```

with

```
Preference
```

so your code will be like this

```
<Preference
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:title="Version "
        android:key="edit_text_preference_1"
        android:summary="1.0" 
        android:enabled="true" />
```

hope this help you